# Celebrate middleware express - NodeJS - not work with mode full

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying use celebrate midleware with mode full activated, but doesn't work, i send request only field nome but the error is only about field "ativo", if i put field "ativo" in request the error is about descricao, I would like receive the "full error" about all validate errors.

```
const insert =  celebrate({
[Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
    nome: Joi.string().required().max(255),
    ativo: Joi.string().required().max(1),
    descricao:Joi.string().required().max(255),
    })
},{},{mode:'full'});
```

Answer (score 0):

To full mode work properly on Celebrate, the joiOpts must have the abortEarly as false.

So, your code should be something like that:

```
const insert =  celebrate({
    [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
        nome: Joi.string().required().max(255),
        ativo: Joi.string().required().max(1),
        descricao:Joi.string().required().max(255),
    })
},{abortEarly: false},{mode:'full'});
```

Here is the issue where I have got this information from:
https://github.com/arb/celebrate/issues/228